# Running program on startup

Tags: bash, startup-applications

I wrote a program in Bash, and now I want to run it on startup for all users so that nobody can cancel it, except for root. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe something like...**

**A question**

How to run a script with the root rights (so only the root can stop it) on startup ?

**Possible answers**

A) The Upstart /1/ can run scripts/programs with root rights during the boot.

B) You could use existing scripts to start your own script. The Ubuntu Resolution wiki /2/ has an example how to set xrandr commands in kdm/gdm startup scripts.

Earlier(Kubuntu Forums): "FAQ: Autostart / Autorun, Periodic run" /3/.

**Links**

1. http://upstart.ubuntu.com/
2. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution
3. http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3117269.0